# Printing a substring from log

Tags: shell, sed, grep, cut

I have a log line of the following format:

```
2016-08-04 19:12:02,537 INFO  ...<Thread-4> - Got a message [......|clientTradeId=xxxxxxx|timeInForce=xxxx|.....TradeResponseMessage]
```

I would need to extract all line with the 'Got a message' key phrase;and then print out just the 'clientTradeId=xxxxxxx' part of the resulting shortlist.

How do I achieve this with scripting(grep and cut? - or is there a better option)

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Considering data is in file data.log

```
grep -F "Got a message" data.log | grep -Po "clientTradeId=[^| ]+"
```

using cut

```
grep -F "Got a message" data.log |  cut -f2 -d'|'
```

Comment: can be done with single grep itself `grep -oP 'Got a message.*\KclientTradeId[^|]+'`

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED COMMAND thanks @BenjaminW:

```
sed -rn 's/.*(clientTradeId=[0-9]*).*/p' file
```

Haven't used sed, but I have used regex.

Looking at the documentation for sed

```
cat file | sed '/.*(clientTradeId=[0-9]*).*/\1/'
```

What this does is pipe the file to sed, then, using regex, select the part that you wanted, then output it (I hope).

Comment: This should probably be a substitution (`s///`) - as it is now, it'll select lines matching `.*(clientTradeId=[0-9]*).*` and then run the command `\1/` on them, which doesn't work. Also, you'd have to use `\(\)` for capture groups, or the `-r` option (`-E` for BSD sed) to use `()`. Finally, no need for `cat`: `sed '<command>' file` is the same, but doesn't spawn a subshell.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm quite new to answering questions. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks fo the insite i will change my answer